# jquery validation displays no error message

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to use jquery validation, but for some reason no error message shows up, even though I try to follow various examples:

```
<form action="/" id="paaForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="testMe" id="testMe" />

<button id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
```

jquery:

```
$(function () {
   $("#paaForm").validate({
    rules: {
        testMe: {
            required: true
        },
  ...
    $('#btnSubmit').on('click', submit);
  ...

function submit() {
    if (!$("#paaForm").valid()) {
        return;
    }
    ...
```

EDITED:

I have to add more information. My application is an MVC application, so it uses bundling like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

This way, MVC validation based on model attributes works perfectly. But I need more complex validation, that is why I added simple jquery validation. And it doesn't work, as I mentioned above. But if I replace bundling with this one,

```
           bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"));
```

jquery validation works, but MVC validation doesn't work, because I exclude 
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js". 
Is it possible to make both work?

Comment: Looks like it should be `return false;` - try just blocking the submit() completely to see if you're not seeing messages because it's POSTing too quick: `function submit() { return false; }`

Comment: do you specify messages in your validate function?

Comment: How are you submitting the form?  There's nothing calling `submit()` in your code, therefore nothing calling `.valid()`

Comment: There is no posting. I am submitting using ajax on a button press.

Comment: Please show full working example. All code necessary, but no more.

Comment: I added some code to my original question.

Comment: $("paaForm").validate({ should be $("#paaForm").validate({ as you are grabbing it by id

Comment: @Denys Fiialko Thank you Denys, I fixed that, but it did not help. "do you specify messages in your validate function?" - no, let it show at least a default message...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've provided.  Here's a jsfiddle for [mcve] given the code in the question:  https://jsfiddle.net/5m6wfj1y/

Comment: What version of jquery and jqueryvalidate are you using?   Could possibly be an issue with mixing different versions.

Comment: @freedomn-m I use jquery-3.3.1 and jquery.validate v1.17.0

Comment: @freedomn-m Please see my addition to the original question. Thanks.

Comment: FYI - if you're using the Unobtrusive Validation plugin, then it constructs the `.validate()` method automatically.  You cannot simply provide your own instance of `.validate()` as it will be ignored.  The plugin is only designed to handle `.validate()` ONE time on any particular form and all subsequent instances are always ignored.  Otherwise, show just enough code to reproduce the issue... the HTML and JavaScript as rendered in the browser.

Comment: Yes, I have already realized that. Would you like to make your comment an answer? I would mark it as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI - if you're using the Unobtrusive Validation plugin, then it constructs the `.validate()` method automatically. You cannot simply provide your own instance of `.validate()` as it will be ignored. The plugin is only designed to handle `.validate()` ONE time on any particular form and all subsequent instances are always ignored.

Answer (score 0):

> Just change one function, then your problem will resolve :-)

```
function submit() {
     if (!$("#paaForm").valid()){
         return false; 
      } 
      ...
      return true;
 }
```

Comment: Still no luck. As I understand, it is all about submitting the form, but I do not submit, I just make an ajax call. I only want to display error message  if the form is invalid.

Comment: Please see my addition to the original question. Thanks.

Comment: do one think, write "$.validator" in your browser console, if it returns "undefined" it means "jquery-validation" plugin is not loaded yet, if it don't return anythink, try different browser's console(current browser console settings may hide)

Comment: also you can execute "alert($.validator);" in your js code, see what will display in alert, if undefined/null it means plugin not loaded properly

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code as below. You need to give access to show error messeges by below jquery plugin. Default validate set `debug: false`. Set it as `true`.

```
$("#paaForm").validate(
   debug: true
});
```

This should work for you. For more about jquery validation [click here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/). Good luck!

Comment: it still doesn't work. I though that debug: true just prevents from submitting.

Comment: Please see my addition to the original question. Thanks.